# github merge origin and master repository

Tags: git, cygwin

I have main repository at github. I have created a fork. I created a branch and made some changes and committed/pushed on github. Now I need to merge main repository and my branch. How can I merge both. I have created  clone of main repositroy. When i try to do

git pull origin branchname

I get

```
  0 [main] us 0 init_cheap: VirtualAlloc pointer is null, Win32 error 487
```

AllocationBase 0x9A0000, BaseAddress 0x9E0000, RegionSize 0x140000, State 0x2000

C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\sh.exe: *** Couldn't reserve space for cygwin's h
eap, Win32 error 0

Please suggest how can I merge both ?

Comment: not sure if i fully understand: you are able to pull the master branch to your local disk? But when you try to pull another branch, your git client fails with the error you posted?

Comment: This shouldn't happen. Does the same error occur with other Git operations? [Other MSYS commands](http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/issues/detail?id=176)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the workflow is something like this:

```
git clone http://remote rep here
... Do work ...
git branch temp
git checkout temp
git pull http://remote rep here
git checkout master
git merge temp
```